# Validar numero de telefono mysql 5.7 chek (variable like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de validar un número de teléfono de 8 dígitos en mysql 5.7 pero no lo logro. Alguien sabe cómo se hace he probado de varias maneras.
Es decir quiero que solo admita por ejemplo: la letra n + 8 números.

Ejemplo: esto funciona en sql server pero no en mysql 5.7

```
CREATE DATABASE universidad;
USE universidad;
CREATE TABLE aula(
numeroAula char(2) NOT NULL CHECK (au LIKE ('G[0-9]'))
);
```

quiero hacer lo mismo en mysql que solo puedan recibir valores que inicie con la letra G y un numero ejemplo: g12, g13 etc, pero que no permita f12, f13
Entiendo que el ejemplo no es de un numero de teléfono, solo quiero ser capaz de poder hacer ese tipo de restricciones en mysql.

Comment: Agrega el código que has intentado.

Comment: listo he agregado un ejemplo.

Comment: mas que todo conocimiento, tengo claro que puedo hacerlo en el lenguaje, saludos.

Comment: Según el manual, hasta MySQL 8.0.16 esos `CHECK` son [ignorados](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)